# .htaccess and file permissions of WordPress on VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress installation on my VPS. Why is it when I try to change the permalink settings from `?p=123` to `/2014/04/sample-post/` I will get 404 Not Found error? What are the needed file permissions for WordPress?

Also, I already enable `https://www` for my site. How can i redirect all visitors who access the `http://`, `http://www` and `https://` to `https://www` ?

Answer (score 0):

To enforce https: Sign in into your admin panel, Settings -> General. In `WordPress Address (URL)` replace `http` with `https` and same with `Site Address (URL)` and WordPress will magically enforce `https`, same way you can enforce `www` by typing it in front of your domain name.

With permalinks, are you sure that your server supoorts htaccess? If you got nginx server, you might want to have a look here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

File permissions should be 755.